# RabbitMQ empty queues in the admin dashboard when using .NET core RabbitMQ.Client

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq

I have been using .NET Core and RabbitMQ client to publish the messages in the queue. I am using the official RabbitMQ docker image and I can validate that the **BasicPublish** method is working fine and I can get the message as well. However, When I open the admin dashboard, I do not see any queues and messages over there.

This is the first time when I am using RabbitMQ so can someone please highlight where I am making mistake ? I am also pasting code for the reference.

```cs
channel.QueueDeclare(queue: queueName, durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);

var message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(publishModel);
var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

IBasicProperties properties = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
properties.Persistent = true;
properties.DeliveryMode = 2;

channel.ConfirmSelect();
channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "", routingKey: queueName, mandatory: true, basicProperties: properties, body: body);
channel.WaitForConfirmsOrDie();
channel.ConfirmSelect();
```

[RabbitMQ Admin Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tkbga.png)

Let me know if more details are required.

Comment: You say :  `... I can get the message as well`. How do you get the message? Console test program?

Comment: where are you configuring the rmq server details?

Comment: @Vernou, yes I can get the messages in the code.

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya: In the startup file of the project. The connection is established that I have verified.

Startup file Code:

          services.AddSingleton<IRabbitMQConnection>(con =>
            {
                var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
                {
                    HostName = Configuration["EventBus:HostName"],
                    UserName = Configuration["EventBus:UserName"],
                    Password = Configuration["EventBus:Password"]
                };
                return new RabbitMQConnection(factory);
            });

Comment: `When I open the admin dashboard, I do not see any queues and messages over there.` Do you select the correct VHost?

Comment: @TAYYABSUHAIL can you try hard coding the values to cross check if you are having correct values

Comment: @krishnaChaitanya: The issue has been resolved, I was using docker image for the RabbitMQ and somehow delete and re-create the container worked for me. Thanks for the help though :)